# Angular 9: How to get data from parent component in child directive

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-components, angular9

I have parent component with child directive inside of it. Needs to get input data from the component in the directive.

```
<my-parent [data]="'Hello from parent'">
  <input myChild>
</my-parent>
```

**Parent Component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-parent',
  template: `
    <ng-content select="[myChild]"></ng-content>
  `
})
export class ParentComponent {
  @Input() data: string;
}
```

**Child Directive**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[myChild]'
})
export class ChildDirective implements OnInit {
  value: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    // needs to get data from parent component here
  }
}
```

I can inject parent component into directive, but I don't want to do this, because it increases the risk of cyclical dependencies.

I can use `@ContentChild` in ParentComponent and pass data in `AfterContentInit` via public property, but I am not sure when this property will be available in ChildDirective, should I use `AfterContentChecked` for this case or not?

**Parent Component**

```
@ContentChild(ChildDirective, {static: true}) child: ChildDirective;

ngAfterContentInit() {
  this.child.value = this.data;
}
```

**Child Directive**

```
value: string;

ngAfterContentChecked() {
  // will be available data from parent here?
}
```

Maybe I should use service to share data between the component and the directive?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pass-data-to-child-directive

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason you need to be using ng-content instead of an ng-template?

I suggest you use an approach with ng-templates as follows

**Parent Component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-parent',
  template: `
    <ng-template 
      [ngTemplateOutlet]="child" 
      [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: data }">
    </ng-template>
  `
})
export class ParentComponent implements AfterContentInit {
  @Input() data: string;
  @ContentChild(TemplateRef, {static: true}) child: TemplateRef<any>;
}
```

**Child Directive**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[myChild]'
})
export class ChildDirective {
  @Input()
  value: string;
}
```

**Usage**

```
<my-parent [data]="'Hello from parent'">
   <ng-template let-dataThroughParent>
      <input myChild [value]="dataThroughParent" class="form-control">
   </ng-template>
</my-parent>
```

**IMPORTANT**

In this specific case (of the example) it is not really necessary to bind the data to your parent, then get it through the template variable and then bind it again to your "myChild" directive as it would be redundant and unnecessary, if your use case resembles this, I would pass the data directly to "myChild" directive as follows:

```
<my-parent [data]="'Hello from parent'">
   <ng-template>
      <input myChild [value]="'Hello from parent'" class="form-control">
   </ng-template>
</my-parent>
```

*Note that it would work for your initial approach too by doing :*

```
<my-parent [data]="'Hello from parent'">
  <input myChild [value]="'Hello from parent'">
</my-parent>
```

But I am assuming you truly need to pass data from the parent that is not accessible in the scope where you use the parent. Here is a working example

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pass-data-to-child-directive-ebcbg6

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data to the directive with `@Input()` binding.

app.component.html

```
<my-parent [data]="'Hello from parent'"></my-parent>
```

my-parent.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-parent',
    templateUrl: './my-parent.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./my-parent.component.scss'],
})
export class MyParentComponent implements OnInit {

   @Input() data: string;
}
```

my-parent.component.html

```
<input [myChild]="data"/>
```

my-child.directive.ts

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[myChild]'
})
export class ChildDirective implements OnInit {
  value: string;

@Input('myChild') data: string;

  ngOnInit() {
      console.log(this.data) // data from parent
  }
}
```

https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives

Comment: I considered this as an answer, it seems intuitive but when I tried it actually the [myChild]="data" is evaluated from the context of where you are using "my-parent" component not from "my-parent" component itself, so this results in a "data not found" since the attribute data does not exist outside "my-parent"

Comment: I edited the answer with new code examples. I think you might have used incorrect syntax on when you put the `input` tag between the `my-parent` tags. I just don't know such syntax in angular.

Comment: It's a different use case that you are answering to, in his question he wants to be able to provide custom content to his "my-parent" component depending on where he calls it and what he wants to do with it, that's what "ng-content" (content projection) is for, check out: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-content/ it explains it well.

Comment: Oh I thought you asked the question. I'll read what you linked. Meanwhile, the syntax he used is valid?